# How to make a lightweight Swing or AWT component translucent in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, transparency

A while ago, I tried to implement a semitransparency method for Swing/AWT components, and just now tried it out for the first time. However, several glitches in the UI surface upon implementation. The code of the method is below:

```
  public static void setTransparency(Component comp, float t)
  {
    try
    {
      if (comp instanceof Window)
      {
        try
        {
//For JDK 1.7
          ((Window) comp).setOpacity(t);
        }
        catch (Throwable th)
        {
          System.err.println("JRE may be less than 1.7!");
          if (!th.getClass().isInstance(new NoSuchMethodError()))
            th.printStackTrace();
          try
          {
//For JDK 1.6
            com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity((Window) comp, t);
          }
          catch (Throwable th1)
          {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("It seems that transparency is not supported", th1);
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (comp instanceof JComponent)
          ((JComponent)comp).setOpaque(false);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) comp.getGraphics().create();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, t));
        comp.paint(g2);
        g2.dispose();
      }
    }
    catch (Throwable th)
    {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Transparency might not be supported", th);
    }
  }
```

When run, the component does not change in appearance. **Does anyone have a suggestion for making a Swing or AWT component semitransparent that is 100% reliable?** This only applies to lightweight components, as heavyweight transparency is separately covered and 100% reliable, as shown above.

Comment: Does this happen when setting a _Window_ translucent or a _component_?  And with what JDK version?

Comment: @prunge as I said in the last sentence, it is only components. Window semitransparency works perfectly. I am testing on JDK 1.7_1 and JDK 1.6_29

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for JComponent#setOpaque(false)?

The code you posted makes no sense (trying to paint it transparent once won't last)

Comment: @WalterLaan do you even know what `JComponent#setOpaque(boolean b)` does? That is NOT what I want. I want semitransparency of the entire component, not an on/off of its background.

Comment: If any part of the background must show through to your component, then your component must set opaque to false.  So yes, that is what you want.

Comment: Alright, fine. To entertain you, I set the target component to not opaque. The question has been modified to fit the new behavior of the program.

Comment: @Supuhstar: No need for the snarky responses to @WalterLaan and @JimN. You have misunderstood the meaning of `setOpaque` and `isOpaque`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you might wan to look at JLayer (or JXLayer for < Java 1.7) for transparency then.

See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: That's great, and I'll probably end up using something like that. However, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's your first problem:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) comp.getGraphics().create();
g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, t));
comp.paint(g2);
g2.dispose();
```

You should only be painting components inside a call to `paint(Graphics g)`. Painting during a call to your `setTransparency` method is A Bad Idea, because it will be erased the next time Swing decides to call `paint`. You need to make your component handle it's own transparency inside the `paintComponent` method.

Also this: `if (!th.getClass().isInstance(new NoSuchMethodError()))`

What on earth are you doing? What's wrong with a simple `catch (NoSuchMethodError e)`? Or, if you *really* want to use instanceof then `th instanceof NoSuchMethodError`?

By the way, @WalterLaan and @JimN know what they're talking about. `setOpaque` (or, more accurately, `isOpaque`) is a rendering hint to the Swing engine that can help it optimize it's operation. Check the javadocs and you'll see what I mean. It's nothing to do with turning the background on or off. Well, that's not *entirely* true - `JComponent`, by default, does some cleverness with the `opaque` property to automatically paint the background if appropriate, but if you're handling your own painting then that cleverness will probably be overridden.

EDIT: Regarding the NoSuchMethodError. Take a look at this:

```
void setTransparency(Window w, double t) {
    try {
        setOpacity17(w, t);
        return;
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        System.err.println("JRE *is* less than 1.7!"); // We know the JRE must be < 1.7 because the right methods are known to exist in 1.7.
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        setOpacity16(w, t);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Boom!");
    }
}

void setOpacity17(Window w, double t) {
    ...
}

void setOpacity16(Window w, double t) {
    ...
}
```

That's a lot cleaner. Note the `return` that will short-circuit the function if the 1.7 version succeeds.

Comment: A: I don't think I can statically change the `paint` method of any arbitrary component. If I can, please tell me how.
B: Firstly, a `NoSuchMethodError` is not "simple", and I am catching it because `Window#setOpacity(float f)` does not exist in JREs less than 7, and so I then don't have to print the stack because I know what's going on and the next code to be run will work for JRE 6.u
C: I checked the Javadocs, and I concede to your wisdom. However, I thought they meant that setting it to be not opaque was the entire solution

Comment: @Supuhstar: So you don't control the component that you want to make translucent? I assumed it was your own component that your were trying to make translucent. In any case, you can probably just wrap each of the components you want translucent inside another component that *does* know about translucency, and use alpha blending there.

Comment: @Supuhstar: What's not simple about NoSuchMethodError? `try { doSomething17Specific(); } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) { doSomething16Specific(); }` should do the trick for you.

Comment: it's not the handling that's not simple, but what leads to its occurrence. As with all extensions of `Error`, a `NoSuchMethodError` means that the compiled code doesn't match up with existing libraries, and can't execute. This isn't as simple a fix as, say, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: My point was that you can still *catch* it with a simple `catch (NoSuchMethodError e)`, rather than your elaborate (and slow) `getClass().isInstance(new NoSuchMethodError())`. What you actually do after catching it is an entirely different question.

Comment: Yes, well I don't WANT to catch it, but rather to know whether there's a point to printing the stack trace. I know what is going on if a `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown, but I don't necessarily know for any other `Throwable`

Comment: @Supuhstar: You **are** catching it inside your `catch (Throwable)` clause. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: That's very clean of you and I think I'll implement it. Now, back on topic :P